# R Zoo - aggregating many records with same time entry

Tags: r, zoo

I consistently need to take transaction data and aggregate it by Day, Week, Month, Quarter, Year - essentially, it's time-series data.  I started to apply `zoo`/`xts` to my data in hopes I could aggregate the data faster, but I either don't fully understand the packages' purpose or I'm trying to apply it incorrectly.

In general, I would like to calculate the number of orders and the number of products ordered by category, by time period (day, week, month, etc).

```
#Create the data
clients <- 1:10
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012/1/1"), as.Date("2012/9/1"), "days")
categories <- LETTERS[1:5]
products <- data.frame(numProducts = 1:10, 
                       category = sample(categories, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                       clientID = sample(clients, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                       OrderDate = sample(dates, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

I could do this with `plyr` and `reshape`, but I think this is a round-about way to do so.

```
#Aggregate by date and category
products.day <- ddply(products, .(OrderDate, category), summarize, numOrders = length(numProducts), numProducts = sum(numProducts))

#Aggregate by Month and category
products.month <- ddply(products, .(Month = months(OrderDate), Category = category), summarize, numOrders = length(numProducts), numProducts = sum(numProducts))

#Make a wide-version of the data frame
products.month.wide <- cast(products.month, Month~Category, sum)
```

I tried to apply `zoo` to the data like so:

```
products.TS <- aggregate(products$numProducts, yearmon, mean)
```

It returned this error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  'by' must be a list
```

I've read the `zoo` vignettes and documentation, but every example that I've found only shows 1 record/row/entry per time entry.

Do I have to pre-aggregate the data I want to time-series on?  I was hoping that I could simply group by the fields I want, then have the months or quarters get added to the data frame incrementally to the X-axis.

Is there a better approach to aggregating this or a more appropriate package?

Comment: What do you mean by "months or quarters get added to the data frame incrementally to the X-axis"?

Comment: I was thinking like an OLAP cube - The category would be on the Y axis, then Jan, Feb, Mar... Sept 2012.  The answer you gave will get me to that, or to quarters.  I just need to figure out how to group by category or ClientID now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`products$numProducts` is a vector, not a zoo object.  You'd need to create a zoo object before you can use method dispatch to call `aggregate.zoo`.

```
pz <- with(products, zoo(numProducts, OrderDate))
products.TS <- aggregate(pz, as.yearmon, mean)
```